# Understanding definition and integration on $n-1$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold.

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have basically given a parametrisation $x$ with $\operatorname{rank}(Dx)=n-1$. I understand, that the differential therefore spans an $n-1$ dimensional object, since the columns are linear independent.

Now the author states that we have a normal vector given by $\nu=(\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_n)$, whereas

$$\nu_i=(-1)^{n+i}\operatorname{det}\bigg(\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial t_j}\bigg)_{j\in\{1,\ldots, n-1\},\\ k\in\{1,\ldots, n\}\backslash\{i\}}$$

I am struggling with verifying, that $\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t_j},\nu\rangle=0$ for each $j\in\{1,\ldots, n-1\}$.

I also understand, that normalisation of this vector is easily given by dividing with $\sqrt{\nu_1^2+\ldots+\nu_n^2}$.

But now again I struggle with understanding, why this normalisation factor is used for defining the integral. The author states:

$$\int_{x(T)}f(x) do(x):=\int_T f(x(t)) \sqrt{\nu_1^2(t)+\ldots+\nu_n^2(t)}dt$$

This factor must somehow be some sort "volume" factor, but how is this meant to be understood?

Thanks in advance for any help on

1. why $\nu$ is a normal vector.
2. why $\sqrt{\nu_1^2+\ldots+\nu_n^2}$ is the right factor for defining the integral.

(**Comment on the parametrisation:** An injective map $x:\overline{T}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x\in C^1(T,\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(\overline{T},\mathbb{R}^n)$, whereas $T\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is bounded and pathwise connected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any column of $Dx$ and put it as $n$-nth column next to it. Let's call that $(Dx|\frac{\partial x}{\partial t_j})$. Since the columns are clearly linear dependend, it holds

$$0=\operatorname{det}\big(Dx|\frac{\partial x}{\partial t_j}\big)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t_j}\cdot (-1)^{n+i}\cdot\operatorname{det}\big(\frac{\partial x_l}{\partial t_k}\big)=\langle \frac{\partial x}{\partial t_j},\nu\rangle$$

Also one can show, that $\sqrt{\nu_1(x)^2+\ldots+\nu_n(x)^2}$ is the same as taking the square root of the usual Gram determinant with respect to the $n-1$ columns that occur in $Dx$. I forgot the calculation, but it's not difficult. Just leave a comment, if it's needed.