# Is this definition of the normal vector incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

In the book I'm reading( Vectors, Tensors, and the basic equations of fluid dynamics by Rutherford Aris) they give the following definition of the normal vector:

$$n_i = \frac{1}{2}e^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{ijk}t_{\alpha}^{j}t_{\beta}^{k}$$

Where,

$$e^{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}}{\det(a_{\alpha\beta})}, t_{\alpha}^{i}= \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial u^{\alpha}}$$

$\epsilon_{i_{1}...i_{n}}$ is the Levi-Civata symbol of n indices, $x^{i}$ are the coordinates of space, $u^{\alpha}$ are the coordinates of the surface, and $a_{\alpha\beta}$ is the metric tensor of the surface. When I worked out $n_{1}$ I got: $$\frac{t_{1}^{2}t_{2}^{3}-t_{1}^{3}t_{2}^{2}}{\det(a_{\alpha\beta})}$$ When I applied this to the sphere I got $-\sin(u^{2})\cos(u^{1})$. Where $u^{1}=\varphi$ and $u^{2}=\theta$(in spherical coordinates). Which is off by a minus sign. I checked the definition of the third order Levi-Civita symbol and they match up. So does this book use a different definition of the second order Levi-Civita symbol or is there an error in my summations?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like the cross product of tangential vectors, divided by its norm. You might consider to look at my answer on following topic, too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589854/understanding-definition-and-integration-on-n-1-dimensional-c1-submanifold Hope this will help!

Comment: Your $u^i$ are oriented opposite to the convention, e.g., at $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$ your $u^1$ direction is positive $y$ and $u^2$ direction is negative $z$, giving the inward normal instead.

Comment: @user10354138 Oh! So the first formula is for the inward normal and if I want the outward I'd have to multiply by (-1)?

Comment: No, the formula is for the normal which gives the compatible orientation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the surface.  It is your choice of $u^i$ that determines whether it would be inward or outward (I'm assuming your spherical polars convention is $(x,y,z)=(r\sin\theta\cos\phi,r\sin\theta\sin\phi,r\cos\theta)$).

Comment: @user10354138 I think I get it, thank you!